# lost my phone with 2FA code

Tags: security

I lost my phone, so I lost my 2FA code too. 
Now I have new phone and I cant to login to the my wallet in step 2. where I need to get 2FA code from Authenticator.
I am using Monero app on iphone.

I have numbers there.

Please help me with.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the name of the wallet app?

Answer (score 1):

You’l need an Authenticator installed on new device. You can use your back up code/ recovery key to restore your account access.
Get your back-up code that you saved at the time of setting up 2FA with your older phone. This document has the recovery key that you can now use to restore Poloniex account on your Authenticator app.

P.S found it with a simple search on google ;)